# Extract and implode specifics items in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like :

```
data : [Object { name="Nom", type="string"}, Object { name="Prénom", type="string"}]
```

So, with `data[0].name` i can get the first value of `name`, the same with `data[1]` etc...

How can i just and simply concat or implode these values ? I want all `name` values of my object in a string like "AAA, BBB, CCC, CCC"

Edit : my bad, what i need is an array of string like ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]

Comment: Why can't you do data[0].name? var data = [ { name: "Nom", type :"string"}, { name:"Prénom", type:"string"}];
console.info(data[0].name);

Comment: Your edit means you just require the `map` part of @Andy's answer: `data.map(function (item) { return item.name; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var out = data.map(function (el) {
  return el.name;
}).join(', ');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/36nk9jyf/)

`map` returns an array, and `join` joins the array into a string using the delimiter. If you want to return an array, just leave off the `join` part of the code:

```
var out = data.map(function (el) {
  return el.name;
});
```

If you want a function that can allow you to provide a key of your choice:

```
function group(data, key) {
    return data.map(function (el) {
        return el[key];
    });
}

group(data, 'name'); // "Nom, Prénom"
group(data, 'type'); // "string, string"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h1kq34j7/4/)

Comment: My bad, what i need is an array of string, check my edit.. :)

Comment: Just leave off the `join` in that case. `map` will return an array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution with .reduce() method:

```js
var data = [
 { name: "Nom", type: "string"}, 
 { name: "Prénom", type: "string"}
];

var concatenated = data.reduce(function(result, obj) {
 result.push(obj.name);
 return result;
}, []).join(", ");

console.log(concatenated);
```

This will give result like this:

```
Nom, Prénom
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for a function that is already in the language? There isn't such a thing but you can of course write one yourself.

As a fan of functional programming, I believe the best way is:

```
var namesImploded = data.reduce(function (previous, current) {
    return previous.name + current.name;
}, "")
```